# send json by rabbitmq web

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, amqp

I need to send json using rabbit mq web

I have the following structure of email json, you can see on photo. I listen queue using org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListener;

and have the follwing exception - No method found for class java.util.LinkedHashMap

is there any way to deal with it?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I managed to manually send a message by defining a `__TypeId__` header, with value corresponding to the class that represents your message payload:

`__TypeId__ = your.message.class`

Note that the value has to be your class' canonical name, including its package path.

When you don't specify this header, Spring tries to desserialize your payload string to a `LinkedHashMap` by default.